# C++ Concurrent Queue with Primitive Types

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, queue

Can you not have a concurrent queue of primitive types? I'm using the concurrent_queue object from ppl.h in C++ and am initializing my queue as such:

```
iQueue = new concurrency::concurrent_queue<int>;
```

I notice that if I push an int to the queue as such:

```
iQueue->push(num);
```

And then try to pop it from another thread, I can only ever get a single value from the queue - that's it. No matter how many times I push, it's just a single value that comes out. Do concurrent queues not work with primitive types like int?

Is there another way I can do this? Thanks

I'm using the Windows MFC framework for this so might be more difficult to reproduce. Basically, in my main thread I have:

```
concurrency::concurrent_queue<int>* iQueue = new concurrency::concurrent_queue<int>;
```

And then, the below, that gets called for every event that happens (in MFC):

```
iQueue->push(num);
```

Then, in a worker thread I have:

```
while (1) {
    int temp;
    if (queue->try_pop(temp)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206547/discussion-on-question-by-cmed123-c-concurrent-queue-with-primitive-types).

Answer (score 0):

Queues are usually designed to operate on single items only - items are pushed/popped one at a time in first-in-first-out order.

What would you like to do? Perform batch operations where you can push or pop multiple items at once? If yes, how many? 10, 100, the whole queue? I know of proposals for lock-free queues that support batch operations, but I am not aware of any generally available implementations. However, if you can provide a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve, I might be able to help with a solution.